# How do we copy file which only are named as hash format

Tags: command-line, bash, syslinux

I have a list a file in a directory1 and I need to copy the only hash file existing to another directory2. How can I do it using a script? for any other file with a normal name I can do it but what about the hash? do we need parsing to do that?
file name are in this form e6a0feaeh74b94f91419795647be61801b06ecec912087c14907da77f90d6e1a

Comment: A file is a file is a file is a file ... you can copy it as any other file. Or are there any thing that I miss?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a file with a list of hashes, you want to check the hashes of the files in a directory and copy the matching file to another directory? Are the files named by their hash?

Comment: @Arronical I mean by that, I have repertory containing a bunch of files. Among these files, there are some files with name hash like described above. How can I just select the one with the hash naming form and copy it to another directory?

Comment: @SorenA so I should just copy it like so 'cp e6a0feaeh74b94f91419795647be61801b06ecec912087c14907da77f90d6e1a' ?

Comment: If that is the name of the file you get when you use the ls command, then assuming directory2 is under the root directory, and you are currently in the directory where the file is, the command would be `cp e6a0feaeh74b94f91419795647be61801b06ecec912087c14907da77f90d6e1a /directory2/`

Comment: @nobodyspecial yes I am aware of that but this more manual. What I need is to implement a script that can read this name file among 100 other different files and copy it.

Comment: I don't see how you could create a pattern to pick out those type of files as the pattern would be too generic, unless the other files all have an extension or something to help distinguish them from the hash named files.

Comment: Are there some other files with names such long?

Comment: @nobodyspecial Yes, I agree. Other files are just regular file name with the alphabetic letter only and no extension while hash file is alphanumerical name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the other files have no digits, i.e. 0123456789, in the name as you said then something like this would probably do what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern="[0-9]"

for fn in ./* ; do
    if [[ $fn =~ $pattern ]]; then
        cp $fn ./directory2/
    fi
done
```

Just replace /directory2/ with the correct destination directory you want to copy the file to.

NB: This is a very rudimentary script, it also requires you to be in the directory when you execute it. It could do with some polishing, so modify it as you need to.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I will Assume that your filenames have 64 chars ( ∈ lowercase letters or digits).

Using Perl, you could run something along the lines of

```
perl -e 'for (grep(/^[a-z0-9]{64}$/,<*>)){`mv $_ directory2/`}'
```

- `<*>` expand for all your files,
- `grep(/^[a-z0-9]{64}$/, ...)` selects the 64 long ones

Comment: Nice to see new implementation. I will give it a try